# Parse error with PHP json_encode

Tags: php, json

I'm getting an odd error and I'm not sure why it's happening. I'm trying to send multiple values to my ajax call which is resulting in `undefined`.

I tried to debug it and I realized that my PHP is getting a parse error with my `json_encode`. The reason seems to be with the passing of multiple values. Can anyone explain why is that so?

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$files = glob("images/*.*");

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
}

echo json_encode("array_of_images" => $files, "size_of_array" => sizeof($files));
?>
```

**Update: Ajax Code**

```
<script>
    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "img.php",             
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
        success: function(response){     
            alert(response.array_of_images);
            alert(response.size_of_array);
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
           // alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second value passed to [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) should be options, not more data. You need to make your parameters into an array instead of passing it as 2 values:

```
 echo json_encode(array("array_of_images" => $files, "size_of_array" => sizeof($files)));
```

Comment: Thanks, but why do I still get an undefined  on the following ajax response:
success: function(response){     
                 alert(response.array_of_images);
                 alert(response.size_of_array);
             },

Comment: Try `console.log(response)` before you alert it to find out what exactly it contains.

Comment: Undefined in console.log as well. If I have only say `json_encode($files)` it works.

Comment: Response is undefined? You'd have to show your ajax code to see what's going on there.

Comment: Try changing your dataType to json.

Answer (score 2):

Add header and json_encode receive as parameter an array so it would be like this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(["array_of_images" => $files, "size_of_array" => sizeof($files)]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`json_encode` accepts array. So you must write it like

```
echo json_encode(array("array_of_images" => $files, "size_of_array" => sizeof($files)));
```